# How to show on-click the same pop-up for elements created dynamically?

Tags: javascript, html, events, event-handling

I'm trying to make a little project, Note using localStorage. I want for every note created to have a button with some options, like update the note or remove it, or change the style like make the font bold or italic etc. But I stumbled at adding the events on buttons to show the pop-up. On every button that I click, it shows just the pop from the first note...

index.js

```
import Notes from './notes.js';
import { toggleNoteModalSettings } from './helpers.js';

const notesList = document.querySelector('#notes-list');

// render all the notes
const renderNotes = (items) => {
  // loop through every note
  items.forEach((item) => {
    // create element
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    div.setAttribute('class', 'note-box-content');
    // I don't know way he didn't render,
    // but, is just a bunch of html that
    // represents the note
    div.innerHTML = ``;

    // add div to the html
    notesList.appendChild(div);
  });
};

const notes = new Notes();
// notes.addNote(
//   'exam',
//   `Adding some data to localStorage is as easy as using the setItem() method. I'll use a generic key and value for the names, but they can be any strings.`,
//   '1hr ago'
// );
// notes.addNote(
//   'personal',
//   `If you want to get the value for a particular key, you'll use the getItem() method`,
//   'November 3 2021'
// );
// notes.addNote(
//   'work',
//   `Finally, you can remove the data with removeItem().`,
//   'November 2 2021'
// );
// notes.addNote(
//   'exam',
//   `Using clear() will clear all local storage.`,
//   'November 1 2021'
// );
// notes.addNote(
//   'hobby',
//   `I like making tutorials where you build a small application completely from scratch with plain JavaScript. A to-do list is a common app idea, but without having a database to store the to-dos, it's not particularly useful, and that adds a bit of complexity beyond beginner territory.`,
//   'Novermber 1 2021'
// );
// console.log(notes.getAllNotes());
// localStorage.removeItem('notes');
// console.log(notes.getAllNotes());

// render on page load
renderNotes(notes.getAllNotes());

// add event to every btn
const btnNoteSettings = document.querySelectorAll('.btn-note-settings');
btnNoteSettings.forEach((btn) => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', toggleNoteModalSettings);
});
```

notes.js

```
export default class Note {
  constructor(category, content, timeAgo) {
    this.category = category;
    this.content = content;
    this.timeAgo = timeAgo;
  }

  getAllNotes() {
    let notes;
    if (localStorage.getItem('notes') === null) {
      notes = [];
    } else {
      notes = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('notes'));
    }
    return notes;
  }

  addNote(category, content, timeAgo) {
    const notes = this.getAllNotes();
    // console.log(typeof notes);

    const note = {
      category,
      content,
      timeAgo,
    };

    notes.push(note);
    localStorage.setItem('notes', JSON.stringify(notes));
  }
}
```

helpers.js

```
export const toggleNoteModalSettings = (event) => {
  const modalNoteModalSettings = document.querySelector('.note-modal-settings');

  const element = event.currentTarget;
  // console.log(element);

  if (element) {
    modalNoteModalSettings.classList.toggle('active');
  }
};
```

[an image with the pop-up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhGME.jpg)

Comment: if you check your local storage, does it have the data it's supposed to?.. do you get the correct array in your render function? if yes, does the newly added note get appended correctly to your node list? and does the class get toggled? also good to check if css is applied as planned and if you get the right data, check that the html injection is correct.

Comment: it's all good ...I think, what I can't figure it out is why it shows only the pop-up from the first note, no matter which button I click, if I press the button from the 2nd note the pop-up it should show on that note, not on the first one...